# How to use a callback method to insert data to a polymer property

Tags: javascript, polymer

I have a Polymer page, and I'm trying to push new data to my `my_cart_items` property. If I call `this.AddNewGrocery("data");` in `ready()`, it works; but when I pass that function as a callback in `this.GetGroceryItem("null", "null", this.AddNewGrocery);`, I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: this.push is not a function(…)

I thought the error had to do with the scope, so I tried accessing the local DOM of the page like this:

```
//try 1 not working
Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelector('my-shopview').push('my_cart_items', new CartItem("null","null","Banana1","null","null","null","null"));

//try 2 not working
document.querySelector('my-shopview').push('my_cart_items', new CartItem("null","null","Banana1","null","null","null","null"));
```

I'm not sure what else to do. Can anyone please assist me with this?

```js
class CartItem {
  constructor(groceryId, groceryImgeUrl, groceryName, groceryOrigin, groceryDescription, grocerSaleDetails, groceryDealDetail, grocerySaleTags, produseTypeTag) {
    this.groceryId = groceryId
    this.groceryImgeUrl = groceryImgeUrl
    this.groceryName = groceryName;
    this.groceryOrigin = groceryOrigin;
    this.groceryDescription = groceryDescription;
    this.grocerSaleDetails = grocerSaleDetails;
    this.groceryDealDetail = groceryDealDetail;
    this.grocerySaleTags = grocerySaleTags;
    this.produseTypeTag = produseTypeTag;
  }
}
Polymer({
  is: 'my-shopview',
  properties: {
    my_cart_items: {
      type: Object,
      value: function() {
        return [];
      }
    }
  },
  // Query the database for data
  GetGroceryItem: function(query, count, callback) {
    var message = "null";
    //query the database 

    //callback after we've received the data
    if (callback && typeof callback == "function") {
      return callback(message)
    }
  },
  //Callback method to be called after GetGroceryItem has finished executing
  AddNewGrocery: function(post) {
    //Working when function is called not as a callback method
    this.push('my_cart_items', new CartItem("null", "null", "Banana1", "null", "null", "null", "null"));
    //Try 1 not Working
    //Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelector('my-shopview').push('my_cart_items', new CartItem("null","null","Banana1","null","null","null","null"));
    //Try 2 not Working
    //document.querySelector('my-shopview').push('my_cart_items', new CartItem("null","null","Banana1","null","null","null","null"));
  },
  //After local dom has been initiized
  ready: function() {
    //Populate my cart items with data from firebase
    this.push('my_cart_items', new CartItem("null", "null", "Banana2", "null", "null", "null", "null"));
    this.push('my_cart_items', new CartItem("null", "null", "Banana3", "null", "null", "null", "null"));
    //Get the grocery item's and invove the AddNewGrocery callback method
    this.GetGroceryItem("null", "null", this.AddNewGrocery);
  }
});
```

Here's my stack trace for the other 2 approaches:

```
my-shopview.html:125 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of null(…)
AddNewGrocery @ my-shopview.html:125
GetGroceryItem @ my-shopview.html:115
ready @ my-shopview.html:133
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're invoking a callback that requires `this` to be defined (specifically, `this` should be the same Polymer object from `GetGroceryItem()`), in which case you should use [`Function.prototype.call(this, ...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call):

```
callback.call(this, message);
```

```js
HTMLImports.whenReady(function() {
  Polymer({
    is: 'my-shopview',
    properties: {
      my_cart_items: {
        type: Object,
        value: function() {
          return [];
        }
      }
    },

    GetGroceryItem: function(query, count, callback) {
      var message = "null";

      if (callback && typeof callback == "function") {
        return callback.call(this, message);
      }
    },

    AddNewGrocery: function(post) {
      this.push('my_cart_items', 'Banana1');
    },

    ready: function() {
      this.push('my_cart_items', 'Banana2');
      this.push('my_cart_items', 'Banana3');
      this.GetGroceryItem("null", "null", this.AddNewGrocery);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.7.0/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
</head>
<body>
  <my-shopview></my-shopview>

  <dom-module id="my-shopview">
    <template>
      <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[my_cart_items]]">
        <div>[[item]]</div>
      </template>
    </template>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/RorzxY?editors=1010)

Comment: @DolapoToki No problem :)